# Exposing nested control of User Control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've a user control which contains some nested control such as button, label, etc.

I would be able to expose those controls at design mode in order to setting their property through visual studio properties panel.

it seems to be impossibile to accomplish...is there any way to make it?